# Phone number formating help in php

Tags: php, phone-number

I am a php novice and know there is a simple solution, however I can't seem to find it. I am looking to perge the field of user entered symbols on return and apply formatting.

```
static function getFormatedNum($num){
    if(empty($num)){}else{
    $first=  "(".substr($num, 0, 3).")";
    $second= substr($num,3,3)."-";
    $third=substr($num,6,4);
    $num=$first.$second.$third;}
    return $num;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: doing all the work in the same function

```
function getFormatedNum($num){
    //first strip all the non-digit characters from the input
    $num = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $num);
    //and only then re-format the phone-number   
    if(!empty($num)){
      $first=  "(".substr($num, 0, 3).")";
      $second= substr($num,3,3)."-";
      $third=substr($num,6,4);
      $num=$first.$second.$third;
    }
    return $num;
}
//test
echo getFormatedNum("408.807.9565");
```

**Output:**

```
(408)807-9565
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help on this, I know it is a novice question and I appreciate your time.

Comment: Is there any way to keep it within the same function?

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming input is of format: 5555555555*

```
function getFormattedNum($num)
{
    if($num){
        return "(" . substr($num,0,3) . ")"
            . substr($num,3,3) . "-"
            . substr($num,6);
    }
}
```

Comment: remove the formatting first by `$num = str_replace("-", "", $num);`

Comment: @SableFoste That would not be sufficient. See alfasin's answer for the all-encompassing method to remove formatting.

Answer (score 1):

This does not account for all formats, Some phone numbers can be placed in different formats and can't just be done via checking for 011, or length. You would need a complete list of all area codes/combination to check against for each possible length.

http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/making-international-calls-from-the-united-states
For example, you might see a phone number in the United Kingdom (UK) expressed one of these ways:

(+44) (0)20 7930 4832
+44 20 7930 4832
020 7930 4832

Simple solution might be. Also i'm not happy with this code, i'm sure if can be simplified about a thousand times.

```
private function cleanNumber($uglyNumber){

    $number = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$uglyNumber);
    if(($check = substr($number,0,3))!=='011'){
        //NON 011 Numbers

        switch(strlen($number)){
            //Same Area Code 
            //123-4567
            case 7:
                $prefix = substr($number,0,3);
                $SLN = substr($number,3,10);
                $cleanNumber = $prefix.'-'.$SLN;
                break;

            //Domestic US
            //No International Number
            case 10:
            $area = substr($number,0,3);
            $prefix = substr($number,3,3);
            $SLN = substr($number,6,10);
            $cleanNumber = '('.$area.') ' .$prefix.'-'.$SLN;
                break;

            case 11:
            // International Number [1]
                $country = substr($number,0,1);
                $area = substr($number,0,3);
                $prefix = substr($number,4,3);
                $SLN = substr($number,7,10);
                $cleanNumber = '['.$country .'] ('.$area.') ' .$prefix.'-'.$SLN;
                break;

            case 12:
            // International Number [12]
                $country = substr($number,0,2);
                $area = substr($number,0,3);
                $prefix = substr($number,4,3);
                $SLN = substr($number,7,10);
                $cleanNumber = '['.$country .'] ('.$area.') ' .$prefix.'-'.$SLN;
                break;

            case 13:
            // International Number [123]
                $country = substr($number,0,3);
                $area = substr($number,0,3);
                $prefix = substr($number,4,3);
                $SLN = substr($number,7,10);
                $cleanNumber = '['.$country .'] ('.$area.') ' .$prefix.'-'.$SLN;
                break;

            default:
                //dono 
                return $number;
        }

    }else{
        switch(strlen($number)){

            case 11:
                // ExitUS 001 [1]
                //No Area Code Country
                $exitUs = substr($number,0,3);
                $country = substr($number,3,1);
                $prefix = substr($number,4,3);
                $SLN = substr($number,7,11);
                $cleanNumber = ''.$exitUs .' ['.$country.'] ' .$prefix.'-'.$SLN;
                break;

            case 12:
                // ExitUS 001 [12]
                //No Area Code Country
                $exitUs = substr($number,0,3);
                $country = substr($number,3,2);
                $prefix = substr($number,4,3);
                $SLN = substr($number,7,12);
                $cleanNumber = ''.$exitUs .' ['.$country.'] ' .$prefix.'-'.$SLN;
                break;

            case 13:
                // ExitUS 001 [123]
                //No Area Code Country
                $exitUs = substr($number,0,3);
                $country = substr($number,3,3);
                $prefix = substr($number,6,3);
                $SLN = substr($number,9,13);
                $cleanNumber = ''.$exitUs .' ['.$country.'] ' .$prefix.'-'.$SLN;
                break;

            case 14:
                // ExitUS 001 [1]
                // With Country Code
                $exitUs = substr($number,0,3);
                $country = substr($number,3,1);
                $area   = substr($number,4,3);
                $prefix = substr($number,7,3);
                $SLN = substr($number,10,14);
                $cleanNumber = ''.$exitUs .' ['.$country.'] ('.$area.') ' .$prefix.'-'.$SLN;
                break;

            case 15:
                // ExitUS 001 [12]
                // With Country Code
                $exitUs = substr($number,0,3);
                $country = substr($number,3,2);
                $area   = substr($number,5,3);
                $prefix = substr($number,8,3);
                $SLN = substr($number,11,4);
                $cleanNumber = ''.$exitUs .' ['.$country.'] ('.$area.') ' .$prefix.'-'.$SLN;
                break;

            case 16:
                // ExitUS 001 [123]
                // With Country Code
                $exitUs = substr($number,0,3);
                $country = substr($number,3,3);
                $area   = substr($number,6,3);
                $prefix = substr($number,9,3);
                $SLN = substr($number,12,4);
                $cleanNumber = ''.$exitUs .' ['.$country.'] ('.$area.') ' .$prefix.'-'.$SLN;
                break;

            default:
                //dono 
                return $number;
        }

    }

    return $cleanNumber;
}
```